# Replace particulars characters in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to replace a character to escape it in a Powershell string to convert it to JSON later. I would like to replace the double quotes " in the cmdline by a single quote followed by a double quotes, to escape the double quotes.

I have this string : `user123" -a.exe`

I would like to have `user123'" -a.exe`

I try different combinations with the -replace function like

```
$test -replace '"',''"'
```

but no one works due to the particularity of these characters.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

To force Windows PowerShell to interpret a double quotation mark literally, use a backtick(`) character.

```
PS C:\> $test = "user123`" -a.exe"
PS C:\> $test
user123" -a.exe
PS C:\> $test = $test -replace "`"","'`""
PS C:\> $test
user123'" -a.exe
```

To learn most of the variations and tricks to work with Quotes, type

```
Help about_Quoting_Rules
```

at Powershell console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use backtick(`) character to escape special characters and use *String.Replace* method

```
$test = "user123`" -a.exe"
$test.replace("`"","`'`"")
```

Result:

```
user123'" -a.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a manipulating quoted text, and find the escaping rules are confusing and/or result in obfuscated code, you can also deal with it as here-strings.  Within the here-string delimiters (@'-'@) normal quoting rules don't apply.  It can make for longer code, but may be more intuitive to read and debug or do maintenance on later.

```
$string = @'
 user123" -a.exe
'@

$match = @'
"
'@

$replace = @'
"'
'@

 $string.replace($match,$replace)

 user123"' -a.exe
```

This is obviously a trivial example, but as the amount of quoted text and increases so will the advantage of using the here-strings over constructing arguments inline using escaped characters.