# Powershell syntax - Passing value with double quote

Tags: powershell, escaping

How do I pass double quotes as a parameter in powershell? For example, I need to execute this line but K="Key words" has to be in double quote

```
$Ie.Navigate2("http://inside.nv.com/demo/Search/Pages/results_Table.aspx?k="Boiling Point"(CreatedBy:Broussard AND Write>=6/1/2015 AND Write<=6/30/2015)", 0x10000)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace particulars characters in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153617/replace-particulars-characters-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use encoding.  The (") character would correspond to %22.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 2):

Try to escape the `"` which is part of the parameter string with

> `

so, in your case it will be like below -

```
$Ie.Navigate2("http://inside.nv.com/demo/Search/Pages/results_Table.aspx?k=`"Boiling Point`"(CreatedBy:Broussard AND Write>=6/1/2015 AND Write<=6/30/2015)", 0x10000)
```